# Google API OAuth in php 401 Login Required

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use google api for shopping (merchants) and I'm stuck with this problem.

I'm not very familiar with php, but to me the code seems fine, all I wanna do is try to fetch items from my shop. I've set the client id and client secret in the developer console following the suggested steps by google, but still after logging I get the error.

Here the code I'm using:

```
<?php

/*
 * Uses google API to make an authorized request trough a google dev console project.
 */

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php';
//require_once 'Google/Client.php';
//require_once 'Google/Service/ShoppingContent.php';
require_once '../Config.php';

$redirect_uri = $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; //this is used during the auth process
//$merchantId = $_POST['merchantId'];
$merchantId = Config::MERCHANT_ID;
$service;

$client = Config::getGoogleClient();

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
doOAuth($client);
echo "TOKEN : " + $client->getAccessToken() . " " . $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'];
//after authentication we can create a service object
$service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);

$products = $service->products->listProducts($merchantId);
$parameters = array();
while (!empty($products->getResources())) {
    foreach ($products->getResources() as $product) {
        printProduct($product);
    }
    if (!empty($products->getNextPageToken())) {
        break;
    }
    $parameters['pageToken'] = $products->nextPageToken;
    $products = $service->products->listProducts($merchantId, $parameters);
}

printf("\nEnd");

////////////////////////
//$_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = null;
function doOAuth(&$client) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
    } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
//        $client->setAccessType("offline"); //IMPORTANT
        $token = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $client->createAuthUrl());
        exit;
    }
}

function printProduct($product) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $product->getId(), $product->getTitle());
}
```

And I get the following error:

> 0 Array Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception'
>   with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason":
>   "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header",
>   "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login
>   Required" } } ' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache24\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php:123
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache24\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php(82):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal
>   function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache24\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(181):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apac in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache24\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php
>   on line 123

Thanks for any help

EDIT: further information
I was able to detect this error inside the $token object

> [error] => redirect_uri_mismatch [error_description] => Bad Request
>
> Blockquote

Comment: You will have to set redirect URI in Google API console. It should be same as the location where you are trying to receive the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * IMPORTANT: this url is used during both two phases of OAuth.
 * If a mistmatch of the redirect uri occours during the two phases, the login
 * fails. Must ignore the code (get) parameter in the second phase.
**/
$redirect_uri = "http://localhost/gshop/action/list.php";
```

the old uri was dynamic and with the code parameter